# Getting missing time period value with an interval in My SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch the records with half an hour time interval of the current day with concern data count for that time period.
So, my output came as expected. But, If count(no records) on the particular time period let's say 7:00 - 7:30 I'm not getting that record with zero count.
My Query as follows :

```
SELECT time_format( FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)/(30* 60)) * (30*60)) , '%H:%i')
 thirtyHourInterval , COUNT(bot_id) AS Count FROM bot_activity 
WHERE start_time BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)/(30* 60))
```

For reference of my output :
[image: For reference]

Comment: what will be the `bot_id` when you get 7:30 with count 0 ?

Comment: Sorry, you dont need to consider the bot_id, I can remove that column from select list. Nothing impacts other than same result.

Comment: @Ersoy updated the query. Plese check once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a source for that 7:30 row; a row source for all the time values.

If we have a `clock` table that contains all of the time values we want to return, such that we can write a query that returns that first column, the thirty minute interval values we want to return,

as an example:

```
 SELECT c.hhmm AS thirty_minute_interval
   FROM clock c
  WHERE c.hhmm ... 
  ORDER BY c.hhmm
```

then we can do an outer join the results of the query with the missing rows

```
 SELECT c.hhmm                               AS _thirty_minute_interval
      , IFNULL(r._cnt_bot,0)                 AS _cnt_bot
   FROM clock c
   LEFT
   JOIN ( -- query with missing rows 

          SELECT time_format(...)  AS thirtyMinuteInterval
               , COUNT(...)        AS _cnt_bot
            FROM bot_activity
           WHERE 
           GROUP BY time_format(...)

        ) r
     ON r.thirtyMinuteInterval = c.hhmm
  WHERE c.hhmm ...
  ORDER BY c.hhmm
```

---

The point is that the SELECT will not generate "missing" rows from a source where they don't exist; we need a source for them. We don't necessarily have to have a separate `clock` table, we could have an inline view generate the rows. But we do need to be able to SELECT those value from a source.

( Note that `bot_id` in the original query is indeterminate; the value will be from some row in the collapsed set of rows, but no guarantee which value. (If we add ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to sql_mode, the query will throw an error, like most other relational databases will when non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list don't appear in the GROUP BY are aren't functionally dependent on the GROUP BY )

---

**EDIT**

In place of a `clock` table, we can use an inline view. For small sets, we could something like this.

```
 SELECT c.tmi
   FROM ( -- thirty minute interval
          SELECT CONVERT(0,TIME) + INTERVAL h.h+r.h HOUR + INTERVAL m.mm MINUTE AS tmi
            FROM ( SELECT 0 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                   UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
                   UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 
                 ) h
           CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS h UNION ALL SELECT 12 ) r
           CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS mm UNION ALL SELECT 30 ) m
          ORDER BY tmi
        ) c
  ORDER
     BY c.tmi
```

(Inline view `c` is a standin for a clock table, returns time values on thirty minute boundaries.)

That's kind of ugly. We can see where if we had a rowsource of just integer values, we could make this much simpler. But if we pick that apart, we can see how to extend the same pattern to generate fifteen minute intervals, or shorten it to generate two hour intervals.

Comment: It's throwing error like table "clock" doesn't exists. Was it default one ?

Comment: no. there's no default table named clock. what i was saying that you need a *row source* for that set of time values.  if you have a `clock` table, that has all the time values you want to return, that would be a convenient source. we can use an inline view, any SELECT statement that returns the full set of distinct time values.

Comment: okay, got your point. You mean to say like having a temp table with all half-an hout time interval and needs to join for that query right ?

Comment: yes, that would do it. i'd make the temp table a single column, TIME datatype, PRIMARY KEY, and insert just the half hour intervals.  i'd make that count query return TIME datatype, so the join predicate is on the same datatype, handle formatting the time from the clock table in the outer query.

Comment: `... TABLE clock ( tm TIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (tm) )` and `INSERT INTO clock VALUES ('00:00'),('00:30'),('01:00'),...,('23:30').`

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any query to get current days all half-an-hour records fetching like: 1:00 AM, 1:30 AM,2:00 AM....

Comment: ive added an edit to the answer to show an example inline view that returns time values on thirty minute boundary 00:00 to 23:30 ,  no table references, just inline views, as a standin for a static clock table.  if we are going to be hammering the database repeatedly, the static clock table would be a scalability benefit, vs. repeatedly materializing the view definition over and over.

Comment: Sometimes we'd want to handle the missing rows on the client, rather than in the SELECT.  Where we do want to do it in the SELECT, the "big rock" is that have to have a source for those values to return them.